# Extending twig template when both are within /app directory

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to make custom error pages in symfony2 but having problems using my site theme/layout within error.html.twig

As in stated here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

I've overridden the error file and put my own into `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig`. If I use static content this all works fine, but I'd like to use `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` like I do with all other pages, so I can copy my current layout and styles.

base.html.twig is located at `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig`. How do I go about extending this template?

Also, just out of curiosity, is there any way of overriding error pages from within one of my bundles without making a 'TwigBundle' bundle especially for it?

**UPDATE**

Ok, solved this with the help of 'wouter J'. It turns out the file was being found but the file it was extending was using is_granted. Adding `app.user and` to the if statement as it says in the docs solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `::base.html.twig` syntax is not relative. That means it'll work everywhere.

The full syntax for template paths is `BundleName:DirName:FileName`. So `AcmeDemoBundle:Page:home.html.twig` refers to `@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/views/Page/home.html.twig`.

If the `DirName` is not used, e.g. `AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig`, it'll be resolved to `@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`.

If the `BundleName` is not used, it is assumed the template lives in `app/Resources/views`.

So `::base.html.twig` just refers to the absolute path `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` (this is not absolute, since I don't know the absolute path to the `app` dir in your case, but it'll be absolute when Symfony does it).

**In short**: You can just use `::base.html.twig`

Comment: I'm using `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` currently and it's not working and doesn't seem to find the file. What am I missing? Appreciate the answer btw